# Is there any Sarvo Sapa Vimochana Mantra for all type of Curse?

Tags: curse

By mistake I had given a Sapa (Curse) to somebody but later I realized I should not. Is there any Sapa Vimochana mantra for overall?

Comment: Did u take water in hand and uttered the curse? I think even for cursing one needs to follow some methods :)

Comment: @Rickross - the curse working by words or mantra? I mean if a person hurt then the person says some words (language) or if hurt then he spells some mantra or if hurt then mind then karma become the curse? is mistake curse return who palce the curse ?

Comment: The curse actually work by sankalpa.. by taking water one needs to vow that i am cursing this person for this reason.. i am not sure why mantras are required for cursing? @Kumar

Comment: @Rickross after the curse complete the task it will return to who create the curse via karma?

Answer (score 3):

Curse and blessing is just an assumption of the mind. The jiva’s course is predetermined, and any external factor cannot alter the course. If the person you have cursed has to suffer he will, you cannot alter it. You are just used as an instrument by the almighty to satisfy the course he has set. So do not worry. But do refrain from such acts hereafter.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE. We appreciate your active participation in answering questions on this Q?A forum. But while answering questions on this site its' necessary to provide sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Bhagavad Gita , Puranas , Upanishads etc. And this rule is mandatory. Pure personal opinions and wikipedia / blog sources generally are not encouraged in answers here .Please do provide some sources in your answers from now on. Otherwise it's possible that some of your answers will receive flags and will get deleted from site. Also register on this site as a regular user

Answer (score 1):

You may use
Sarva Mantra Utkilana Shapa Vimochana  -in Shiva Rahasya, Devanagari Tantra

https://archive.org/details/SarvaMantraUtkilanaShapaVimochanaInShivaRahasya4949Alm22Shlf3DevanagariTantra