# How can people overcome a Guru's curse?

Tags: guru, curse

When a Guru curses a person, can that curse be removed by God?

For Example, Lord Parashurama placed a curse on Karna, but Karna was not able to recover from the curse. Are there any situations where the curse of a Guru was overthrown by Gods?

Comment: Curses can never be removed. However, they can be modified.

Comment: Guru himself has to give salvation from the curse. However, it is usually not an exact negation of the curse but a compensating boon.

Comment: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26200/13287

Answer (score 4):

> Guruh pitA gururmAtA gururdevo maheswarah |
>  Shive rushte
>   gurustrAtA **gurau rushte na kaschana** ||
>
> Guru is the father, Guru is the mother, Guru is Lord Maheswara. When
>   Shiva is angry the Guru can be the savior, but when Guru himself is
>   angry none can save.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 12.49*

Similar verses from the "GurugitA Stotram" found in the ViswasAra Tantram:

> Munibhih pannagairvapi surairvA shApito yadi |
>   KAlamrityubhayAdvApi guruh rakshati pArvati ||
>  **Ashakta hi surAh
>   sarve ashaktA munayastathA** |
>  **GurushApah**atAh kshinAh kshayam yAnti
>   na samshayah ||
>
> O PArvati, if the disciple gets cursed by the Munis or by the NAgas or
>   by the Gods, the Guru protects him. The Guru can protect the disciple
>   from even KAla (Yama or death) and from the fear from death. But if
>   Guru himself curses the disciple, then the disciple gradually becomes
>   feeble and eventually attains destruction. And the Gods or the Munis
>   are unable to save him [from the curse] in such cases.
>
> *Verses 63,64 of GurugitA Stotram found in ViswasAra Tantram.*

So, generally it is believed that no one can save the disciple from a Guru's curse. Of course the Guru here is a SathGuru who meets the standards of the scriptures.

....A partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yagyanyavalkya got cursed from his Guru and forgot all Vedas he learnt. As a result he worshipped Maa Saraswati.

[Buddhi stotra](http://ioustotra.blogspot.com/2008/12/shri-buddhi-stotra.html) by Yagnyavalkya starts:

> **krupam kuru jagan matar mamevam hat tejasam || 
>
>   guru shaapaat smruti bhrashtam vidya hinam cha dukhitam ||**

The above stotra belongs to the Brahmavaivarta Purana.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. He asked can that curse be removed. Its generally said that Guru's curse is irrevocable and irreparable without the Guru's grace.

Answer (score 1):

In Hinduism, Guru comes before anyone else, even before God. Also, the first Guru of any human is his/her mother, then comes his/her father then comes the one who teaches other things.

A guru can save you from wrath of any God or rishi or anyone other by showing you the way. But if anyone makes his Guru angry then no one can save him.

It is not that a Guru's curse has more power than anyone. It is just that when you get cursed by anyone the Guru can show you the right path as to minimise the curses's effect, but when you get cursed by Guru then no one can show you any path as you angered the one who shows you the path.

Comment: Welcome to HSE. You want to say there is no way, one can be saved from Guru's curse. You are correct but you should add some verses from scriptures because some scriptural references are almost necessary here. For this answer, you can add this verse from Guru Gita. - शिवे क्रुद्धे गुरुस्त्राता गुरौ क्रुद्धे शिवो न हि।
तस्मात्सर्वप्रयत्नेन श्रीगुरुं शरणं व्रजेत्॥४४॥ 
Translation: When Śiva is angry, the Guru is the Protector, but when the Guru is angry, Śiva is not the Protector, undoubtedly. For that reason, with all one’s own effort one should take refuge in the venerable Guru.